# Down arrows on top of gantt chart bars in JFreechart

Tags: java, user-interface, charts, jfreechart, gantt-chart

I have already built a gannt chart with mouse scroll zoom and horizontal slider. I want to add a triangle in the middle of each sub task bar as shown in figure.

The triangle should not be affected by zoom and always be the same size. (It acts as an indicator for very small task durations.)

[image: Ganntchart with red triangles that need to be added!]

I know I can get the triangle from the ShapeUtilities:

```
Shape arrow = ShapeUtilities.createDownTriangle(4.0f);
```

How can I add these triangles to the existing plot? Should I go with multiple plots overlapped? With two different renderers? Use scatterplot to plot triangles?

I want some suggestions before I go down a blind alley.

A simple [MCV](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example will be most welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to extend the `GanttRenderer` and add a 2nd pass that draws the triangle.

The following renderer should do the trick. Just add the drawing of the triangle to the `drawTriangle` routine.

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

import org.jfree.chart.axis.CategoryAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.ValueAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.CategoryItemRendererState;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.GanttRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.category.CategoryDataset;
import org.jfree.data.gantt.GanttCategoryDataset;

public class TriangleGanttRenderer
    extends GanttRenderer
{
    public TriangleGanttRenderer()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void drawItem(Graphics2D g2, CategoryItemRendererState state, Rectangle2D dataArea, CategoryPlot plot,
        CategoryAxis domainAxis, ValueAxis rangeAxis, CategoryDataset dataset, int row, int column, int pass)
    {
        if (pass == 1 && (dataset instanceof GanttCategoryDataset))
        {
            drawTriangle(g2, state, dataArea, plot, domainAxis, rangeAxis, dataset, row, column);
        }
        else
        {
            super.drawItem(g2, state, dataArea, plot, domainAxis, rangeAxis, dataset, row, column, pass);
        }
    }

    protected void drawTriangle(Graphics2D g2, CategoryItemRendererState state, Rectangle2D dataArea,
        CategoryPlot plot, CategoryAxis domainAxis, ValueAxis rangeAxis, CategoryDataset dataset, int row, int column)
    {
        // ... add your draw routine here ...
    }

    @Override
    public int getPassCount()
    {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does that answer your question? In such a case please mark your question as resolved. Thanks!